# JS invalid/unexpected token: ��#

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, syntax-error

This is the third node project I have gotten the below error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��#
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I have also tried commenting out the entire file and at the end putting `console.log('hello');` but I still get the above error.

- The call is only `node file.js`.
- The error happens at `file.js:1`.
- I'm on a Windows 10 machine
- node v8.9.0
- npm v5.5.1
- Editor: VS-Code

Comment: invalid token can be tricky, post the entire function

Comment: do you want the entire file? Cause I don't know which function it is failing on because doesn't file.js:1 mean that the error happens at line one? which would be a comment in the case of this file. I can also comment out the whole file and just do a `console.log('hello');` and get the same error

Comment: sure, share it here https://pastebin.com/

Comment: show more code in your question..

Comment: the encoding should be utf8

Comment: Looks like a BOM marker, try resaving file without it (VS Code can probably do that)

Comment: Lyth got it. For some reason was set to UTF-16 LE... Thanks

Comment: Can someone add an answer so I can mark as answered?

Comment: @schusterbraun You should answer it yourself.  That is allowed and encouraged.

Comment: @zero298 awesome, thanks. Still new.

Comment: FWIW, came across this today and everything was UTF8. After some desperation, I nuked my node_modules folder, ran npm install and everything started working. To be fair, I did have a hard lock on my machine today, so possible file corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was editing in UTF-16LE. When I switch to UTF-8 code looks like this:
[UTF16 to UTF8 conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odJry.png)